# Revert behaviour of new Firefox 98 regarding downloaded files

Tags: linux, firefox

Up until Firefox version 97, files opened but not downloaded were saved on a hidden "temp" folder, deleted automatically after restart. Since Firefox version 98, they are all downloaded to a visible folder, either chosen by the user or the "Download" one, in Windows/Linux. A super annoying change. [In their own words](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/manage-downloads-preferences-using-downloads-menu#w_set-a-default-app-to-open-a-file-type):

> [image]

How can I manually revert this change? Settings have no option related to this.

Comment: I think there might be some confusion here. That “[Downloaded files are saved to disk](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/manage-downloads-preferences-using-downloads-menu#w_downloaded-files-are-saved-to-disk)” seems to me to be the way downloading files has always worked in Firefox. But your question is “…files opened but not downloaded…” seems to be about non-dowloaded but opened files. Like PDF files, audio and video files and such. Are you 100% on what has changed?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Its the highlighted statement in the image. Before v98, opened but not directly downloaded files (e.g. open pdf in new tab) were put in a temporary folder, out of the view of the user. Now, they are all put in the local user account, usually, Downloads.

Comment: Aaaahhhh… That seems to make sense as to the change in the behavior. What OS are you using? In macOS, Firefox creates a temp file in the `~/Downloads/` directory that I can visually see. And when the download is complete, the temp is renamed and there you go. I wonder if this is a Windows specific thing?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Linux. Image says it's also the case in Windows.

Comment: AFAIK there's still an about:config item for you to revert it...for now

Comment: @TomYan which one? I searched "download" and cannot see one that reverts behaviour.

Comment: `browser.download.improvements_to_download_panel`: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1370409

Answer (score 5):

Make `true` the variable `browser.download.start_downloads_in_tmp_dir` (accessed from `about:config`).

Credit is due to an answer provided by a user named xanthonin the discussion forum http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=3097140